# how to View Versions of comment field in a lists viewform?

Tags: list, view, version, comments

I am trying to show all the verions of comments in a list item As Shown in the image below. I have made the comments column a Append Only column and set Append Changes to existing text to Yes. Now i can see the versions but only it i click on View Entries.

How do i get rid of the view entries text and show the actual version history in the list item?

[image]